# Unable to generate example json value from yaml

Tags: yaml, swagger, schema, jsonschema, openapi

I am trying to parse a given yaml to a JSON example like swagger does. I am using the below yaml.

```
$id: 'https://example.com/person.schema.json'
$schema: 'http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#'
title: Person
type: object
properties:
  firstName:
    type: string
    example:MyName
    description: The person's first name.
  lastName:
    type: string
    description: The person's last name.
  age:
    description: Age in years which must be equal to or greater than zero.
    type: integer
    minimum: 0
```

I am trying to parse this yaml to its json like the below one. If the example is given in the yaml then it should show the example else it should show a default value.

```
Person:{
   "firstName":"MyName",
   "lastName":"string",
   "age":0
}
```

But while parsing I am getting an Exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token '$id': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (String)"$id: 'https://example.com/person.schema.json'
line: 1, column: 4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804) ~[jackson-core-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:703) ~[jackson-core-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2853) ~[jackson-core-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1899) ~[jackson-core-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:757) ~[jackson-core-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4042) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2551) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter.readResourceListing(SwaggerCompatConverter.java:210) [swagger-compat-spec-parser-1.0.44.jar:1.0.44]
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter.read(SwaggerCompatConverter.java:123) [swagger-compat-spec-parser-1.0.44.jar:1.0.44]
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter.readWithInfo(SwaggerCompatConverter.java:94) [swagger-compat-spec-parser-1.0.44.jar:1.0.44]
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser.readWithInfo(SwaggerParser.java:42) [swagger-parser-1.0.44.jar:1.0.44]
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.converter.SwaggerConverter.readLocation(SwaggerConverter.java:92) [swagger-parser-v2-converter-2.0.12.jar:2.0.12]
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.read(OpenAPIV3Parser.java:90) [swagger-parser-v3-2.0.12.jar:2.0.12]
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.read(OpenAPIV3Parser.java:78) [swagger-parser-v3-2.0.12.jar:2.0.12]
    at com.pega.yaml.yamlToJsonExample.App.main(App.java:19) [classes/:na]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.read(OpenAPIV3Parser.java:91)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.read(OpenAPIV3Parser.java:78)
    at com.pega.yaml.yamlToJsonExample.App.main(App.java:19)
```

I am using swagger inflector 2.0.5 with the following code:

```
import io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema;
import io.swagger.oas.inflector.examples.models.Example;
import io.swagger.oas.inflector.examples.ExampleBuilder;

import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import io.swagger.oas.inflector.processors.JsonNodeExampleSerializer;
import io.swagger.util.Json;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        OpenAPI swagger = new OpenAPIV3Parser().read("Eclipse Workspace1\\yamlToJsonExample\\src\\main\\java\\com\\pega\\yaml\\yamlToJsonExample\\Test.yaml");
        Map < String, Schema > definitions = swagger.getComponents().getSchemas();
        Schema model = definitions.get("Person");
        Example example = ExampleBuilder.fromSchema(model, definitions);
        SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule().addSerializer(new JsonNodeExampleSerializer());
        Json.mapper().registerModule(simpleModule);
        String jsonExample = Json.pretty(example);
        System.out.println(jsonExample);
    }
}
```